# Does the order of entires in the iceServers array matter?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

When instantiating an `RTCPeerConnection`, one of the configuration parameters is an array of ICE servers. Straight forward question: Does the order of servers in the array matter? Does the order indicate a preference in any way; should I put servers I'd prefer to be used first, or will the ICE discovery process try them all equally?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. To test you might use [this demo](http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) to check out different orderings and compare the times it takes to gather candidates from the different servers.

Comment: Thanks, interesting link. Can you also illuminate how servers do get chosen? What happens if one server is chronically overloaded? Are all servers tried at once? At random? Any idea?

Comment: All will be tried (which is why it is a pretty bad idea to add 20 stun servers). If a server is overloaded or not reachable no candidates can be gathered.
If you need loadbalancing you need another way

Comment: No, I don't need load balancing. To the contrary… I have a list of authenticated commercial STUN/TURN servers in addition to a handful of public ones; I'd *prefer* if the commercial ones were used, since they probably give the best result… so I was wondering if I should remove the other ones, or whether WebRTC will likely pick the commercial ones anyway if they offer the best connection. Sounds like the latter should be the case, so keeping the public ones as backups should do no harm!?